# Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector

Tags: matlab

I was trying to plot using the following code:

```
x = linspace(0, x, Nx);
y = linspace(0, y, Ny);
z = linspace(0, z, Nz);
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
```

but I get this error:

> Error using `mesh` (line 76)
>   `Z` must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Your code works fine with suitable defined `x`, `y`, `z`, `Nx`, `Ny`, `Nz`; and doesn't even use `mesh`. The error must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a full working example that replicates your error, not just a snippet of code that doesn't even include the line where the the error is.

Nonetheless your problem is that the 3rd input to `mesh` (on your line 76, which you don't show) must be a 2D matrix.  If you are passing the above `X`, `Y`, and `Z` to it then it won't work because they are each 3D matrices.